# Stack Linked implementation import

Tags: java, stack

My problem is with Link<(E)>, is says:

> "sun.awt.image.ImageWatched.Link does not take parameters;"

I've been imported sun.awt.image.ImageWatched.Link;
What's wrong with the code?
How do I make it right?

Here is the code:

```
public class LStack<E> implements Stack<E> {
private Link<E> top=;
private int size;

public LStack(){
    top = null;
    size = 0;
}

public LStack(int size){
    top = null;
    size = 0;
}

@Override
public void clear(){
    top = null;
    size = 0;
}

@Override
public void push(E it){
    top = new Link<E>(it, top);
}

@Override
public E pop(){
    assert top != 0 : "Stack is empty";
    E it = top.element();
    top = top.next();
    size--;
    return it;
}

@Override
public E topValue(){
    assert top != 0 : "Stack is empty";
    return top.element();
}

@Override
public int length(){
    return size;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You refer to `Link<E>` as if `Link` is generic, but it isn't.

I think the real question is: Why are you trying to use `sun.awt.image.ImageWatched.Link` for this? It seems to be intended for a specific purpose that isn't the same as your purpose.

I think you should define your own (generic) `Link<E>` class. All it needs to do is hold a thing of type `E` and a `next` reference.

Comment: can you please explain step by step ?

Comment: If you mean can I please write your code for you: nope, that's not how Stack Overflow generally works. But if there's something specific I wrote that isn't clear enough, feel free to ask.

Comment: mean "hold a thing of type E and a next reference" ?

Comment: I mean that the job of your `Link<E>` class will be to keep track of two things: an object of type `E`, and what comes next in the linked list. The code you've already got indicates how `Link<E>` is expected to be used -- look at how `top` is used in it. I don't want to go into much more detail because it looks to me like this is a homework exercise most of whose *point* is for you to work out what `Link<E>` needs to look like, by looking at the code you've been given...